# Prove that the closure of the following set is compact.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be compact sets of a metric space $X$. Prove that the closure of A\ B is compact. \

Im having doubts with this one. I know by a Theorem that A is closed and B is closed. I know if they are closed means that they are equal to there closure. After that I dont know what to do. Any suggestion I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

The closure of $A/B$ is a closed subset of the compact set $A$, so it is compact. To see this consider a sequence $(x_n\in cl(A/B))$, since $A$ is compact you can extract a subsequence $(x_{f(n)})$ which converges towards $x\in A$, $x\in cl(A/B)$ since $x_{f(n)}\in cl(A/B)$ and $cl(A/B)$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

A closed subset $C$ of a compact set $A$ is compact.  Use the definition of compactness, noting that adjoining $C^c$ to an open cover of $C$  gives an open cover of $A$.